# Xcode 9 iOS Simulator - Unable To Obtain Valid Process Handle

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, ios11, xcode9

I have upgraded to Xcode 9, and the iOS Simulator for 10.3 and 11 are not working. All stock and my apps are force closing when trying to run.

Xcode Console errors like the following show when I try to run Calendar, Preferences etc. What does the "Unable to obtain valid process handle" mean?

---

```
Process handle (com.apple.Preferences, <BSProcessHandle: 0x7fe84552b8b0; Preferences:9270; valid: NO>) is invalid. Returning error {
    BKSProcessExitReason = 0;
    BKSProcessJobLabel = "UIKitApplication:com.apple.Preferences[0x90bf][6825]";
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Unable to obtain valid process handle";
}

[com.apple.Preferences] Bootstrap failed with error: <NSError: 0x600000846c60; domain: BKSProcessErrorDomain; code: 1 (bootstrap-failed); reason: "Unable to obtain valid process handle">

Bootstrapping failed for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x7ffae944f990; com.apple.Preferences; pid: -1> with error: Error Domain=BKSProcessErrorDomain Code=1 "Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID com.apple.Preferences" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to obtain valid process handle, BKSProcessExitReason=0, BSErrorCodeDescription=bootstrap-failed, BKSProcessJobLabel=UIKitApplication:com.apple.Preferences[0x90bf][6825], NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID com.apple.Preferences}

Process handle (com.apple.mobilecal, <BSProcessHandle: 0x7fe845525860; MobileCal:9363; valid: NO>) is invalid. Returning error {
    BKSProcessExitReason = 0;
    BKSProcessJobLabel = "UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilecal[0xf53][6825]";
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Unable to obtain valid process handle";
}

[com.apple.mobilecal] Bootstrap failed with error: <NSError: 0x604000643ae0; domain: BKSProcessErrorDomain; code: 1 (bootstrap-failed); reason: "Unable to obtain valid process handle">

Bootstrapping failed for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x7ffaeb141220; com.apple.mobilecal; pid: -1> with error: Error Domain=BKSProcessErrorDomain Code=1 "Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID com.apple.mobilecal" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to obtain valid process handle, BKSProcessExitReason=0, BSErrorCodeDescription=bootstrap-failed, BKSProcessJobLabel=UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilecal[0xf53][6825], NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID com.apple.mobilecal}

Unable to find framework using path: /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoSubscriberAccount.framework
```

---

I've tried it on iPhone X, iPhone 8/8+ and iPhone 6+ simulators with iOS 11 / 10.3.1, all with the same crashing result. If I try it on older iOS simulators such as iPhone 6+ iOS 9.2, then it runs fine.

If I try to launch it many times, i.e. 40 - 50 times for Safari or Calendar, *sometimes* that specific app may run, and once successfully ran, it'll remain so for the rest of the session (until I close the app at the task switcher, then same problem recurs). The same happens for my Xcode compiled app too.

My iMac 2009 has been running El Capitan and Xcode 8 fine all the while, and I just upgraded to High Sierra with Xcode 9.

I tried Xcode 9.1 Beta, but same problems persisted.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: Please file a bug. Attach the output of 'sysdiagnose -q' and 'xcrun simctl diagnose' with the Simulator booted and after this failure happens. Reply with the radar # so we can investigate.

Comment: Thanks, I'll submit a bug report with the info. I noticed there are many lines in my CoreSimulator.log that writes this: Oct  5 15:56:31 MYMAC CoreSimulatorService[10637] <Error>: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=162 "Incompatible device" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Incompatible device}. What does this mean?

Comment: I've submitted the Bug Report #34829500 with the log files as requested, please investigate and advise on how to fix it, thank you.

Comment: @Andy for some reason the sysdiagnose that you attached doesn't include any crash logs for the processes that you say are crashing.  Can you attach a few of the relevant crash logs from ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports ?

Comment: @Andy Also the `simctl diagnose` seems to have been taken when you had a device booted that you didn't reproduce the issue with.  Thus the log doesn't contain the actual reason for the launch failure.  Can you run `simctl diagnose` while it is reproducing?

Comment: @Andy Actually, it looks like you didn't reproduce the issue with via `xcrun simctl launch` or through Xcode Build & Run.  Can you run `simctl diagnose` while it is reproducing through one of those launch methods as that will capture extra logging.  Thanks.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia I've uploaded a new "xcrun simctl diagnose" report, while I click on the crashing stock apps in the simulator, please see if it's correct. I don't see any relevant logs at Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports though, perhaps because the Simulator is not crashing but the apps within it?

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia Also, I launched the simulator using "open -a Simulator --args -CurrentDeviceUDID XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX" format, is that fine for diagnosis?

Comment: @Andy Can you disable your 3rd-party kernel extensions to see if one of them might be causing this?

Comment: @russbishop You are amazing, that solves the problem, thank you so much! I've found the culprit as Hands Off firewall. Please see my Answer post below for full details. I'll update the bug report and apple developer forum too. How did you figure out it's the kext?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @russbishop's suggestion of disabling 3rd party kernel extensions, I have found the culprit — [One Periodic's Hands Off Firewall](https://www.oneperiodic.com/products/handsoff/)!

I unloaded the kext with this command:

```
kextunload -b com.metakine.handsoff.driver
```

And immediately all the stock apps in iOS Simulator can start perfectly fine. Note that you must ***unload*** the kext. Simply disabling the rules in Hands Off does not fix the problem.

However, I cannot "*kextload*" back the Hands Off driver once I am done to reactivate the firewall. A system reboot is needed.

I have reported this issue to Hands Off as well, and hopefully see a fix in the next release.

Thanks @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia for helping with the diagnosis too.

Comment: Thanks a lot @russbishop, you're da man :) I wonder how many more Xcode developers are affected, since Hands Off is a pretty popular firewall. Your team may wish to contact them if that could expedite the fix.